# 2060 Illegal instruction (core dumped) when importing Tensorflow in Python 3.8.18

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.x

I am attempting to run the experiments found here: https://github.com/risingfbk/p4ddle/tree/main/p4-ddos/p4ddle

However when I run the line:

```
./experiment_**.sh
```

I get this error:

```
(python38) p4@p4:~/Desktop/p4ddle/p4-ddos/p4ddle/control-plane$ ./experiment_**.sh
start lucid with the trace dns, with sampling at 1 packet over 1
Obtaining JSON from switch...
Done
Control utility for runtime P4 table manipulation
RuntimeCmd: RuntimeCmd: 
here
./experiment_00.sh: line 28:  2060 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) python3 lucid_cnn.py --predict_live localhost:22222 --model $model --dataset_type $dataset_type
```

The program fails at runtime, as it fails to compile `lucid.cnn`, the failure line being the
`import tensorflow as tf` line.

```
import json
import csv
print("here")
import tensorflow as tf
print("here")
```

I have looked for a solution and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092527/illegal-instructioncore-dumped-tensorflow
which tells me to downgrade to Tensorflow version 1.5. This is not possible for me as I am using `Python 3.8.18`, and the earliest version of tensorflow compatable is 2.20. Using this version also results in the same error.

I think perhaps it may be a hardware issue? I am using a virtual box vm to run this in. The outputs for lscpu and sudo lshw -C display are shown below:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           140
Model name:                      11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:                        1
CPU MHz:                         2803.210
BogoMIPS:                        5606.42
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       96 KiB
L1i cache:                       64 KiB
L2 cache:                        2.5 MiB
L3 cache:                        24 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx 
                                 rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid ss
                                 e4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ibrs_enhanced fsgsbase b
                                 mi1 bmi2 invpcid rdseed clflushopt md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities


  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
       vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller rom
       configuration: driver=vboxvideo latency=0
       resources: irq:10 memory:e0000000-e1ffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Any help appreciated.